# C# MVC call javascript function on click

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

How to we call a function from an external JS file on click?

JS file on /Content/js/pj_no.js

```
function alertMe(){
    alert("me");
}
```

C#

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/js/pj_no.js")
<input value="親コード新規登録" type="button" onclick="alertMe()" />
```

Assuming this is in the same file iin my csHTML it is working fine. But when I put it on the external JS it is not calling anymore.

I know my JS is in the right directory as if i trigger an $(document).ready(function () {} it is calling the alert. But I need it to be on click event.

Help please

```
$(document).ready(function (
alert("me"); -- This is working,

function alertMe(){ //cant call this function
    alert("me");
}
)});
```

Comment: have you check if your javascript file loaded? you can check it using developer tools in the browser. e.g Press F12

Comment: Yes it was loaded. I run the same script in the same file 
$(document).ready(function (
alert("me"); -- This is working,

function alertMe(){ //cant call this function
    alert("me");
}
)});

Comment: did you see your `pj_no.js` independently with your view?

Comment: Yes. Again in the document.ready, the alert is already working, the function is not. I edited the question :)

Comment: where are you calling `(document).ready` ? in the C# view?

Comment: Calling order of your js and where exactly you where calling it.

Comment: In MVC we rarely uses `onclick` event on input element, usually we use jQuery like this: `$("#elementname").click(function () { alertMe(); });` with `<input value="親コード新規登録" type="button" id="elementname" />`.

Comment: See "Ashokkumar M. Prajapati" answer. That's correct. Modify your code and let us know still you are facing any issue.

Comment: Thanks, its working nowwwwww. @TetsuyaYamamoto thank you

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto is there any way to pass a parameter with that approach?

From
funtion Add(name){
     alert("name");
}


To

 $("#add").click(function () {
     alert("name");   
    });

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte Which parameter do you want to pass? It depends to how the JS function constructed.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto
Im now using a radio button and its on loop.

I need to change this from.

//inside for each loop
<input type="radio" name="option_value" value=item.pj_no onclick="loadRow('item.pjno_id')"> item.pj_no

to

<input type="radio" name="option_value" value=@item.pj_no id="loadRow"> item.pj_no

Notice that in the onclick ="" there is a parameter. that is what i need to do now. Your approach worked on my buttons, but though dont have parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (
  alert("me"); -- This is working,

  // NOTE: Following becomes local function. and will not work
  function alertMe(){ //cant call this function 
      alert("me");
  }
)});
```

You need to make it global to get called. Please declare it out side of document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function (
  alert("me"); -- This is working,

)});
  // NOTE: Following will work 
  function alertMe(){ 
      alert("me");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bundle it first in App_Start > BundleConfig.cs inside `RegisterBundles`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/pj_no").Include(
                        "~/Content/js/pj_no.js"));
```

then you can call it in your view :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pj_no")
<input value="親コード新規登録" type="button" onclick="alertMe()" />
```

Comment: already added the bundle in the folder.
The JS file is already being called, i just cant call the function

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simply put the external js function in script folder.[image]

Then simply call include it on view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/pj_no.js")
```

Then simply call the function on onclick

```
<input value="親コード新規登録" type="button" onclick="alertMe()" />
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if any query

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it will work

```
window.alertMe = function(){ //can call this function
    alert("me");
}
```

Your code is not working because your function gets added to the local scope of `$.ready` function. By using `window.alertMe` your function will be added to global scope even if it is inside the `$.ready` method

Answer (score 0):

It is working now with this way.

In MVC we rarely uses onclick event on input element, usually we use jQuery like this:

```
$("#elementname").click(function () {
 alertMe(); 
});
<input value="親コード新規登録" type="button" id="elementname" />.
```

– Tetsuya Yamamoto